# How to find inverse of generator of a finite field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

I need  to find the inverse of generator of finite field $\mathbb{F}_{2^4}$ with irreducible polynomial , $f(x)=x^4+x+1$ i.e. if $g=0010$ is the generator of this field then how to find $g^{-1}$?

Comment: What do you mean with $g=0010$?

Comment: What Robert Israel writes (+1). If you want to learn a bit more about doing arithmetic operations in this field take a look at [this Q&A](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/591253/11619) I prepared for referrals like this. Your $g$ is denoted $\gamma$ there, so $g^{-1}=g^{14}$ is $\gamma^{14}=\gamma^3+1=1001$.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen :thank you very much,it helped me to understand the logic.

Comment: @Bernard:actually g=0010 was binary string and a generator of finite field.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you mean is: your field $GF_{2^4}$ is represented as $\mathbb F[\alpha]$ where $\mathbb F = \mathbb Z_2$ and $\alpha^4 + \alpha + 1 = 0$,
and your generator is $\alpha$ (or it might be $\alpha^2$, depending on how you're representing things).  Well, multiply that equation by $\alpha^{-1}$ and you see $\alpha^{3} + 1 + \alpha^{-1} = 0$, so $\alpha^{-1} = \alpha^3 + 1$.  A similar idea will work if you're looking for $(\alpha^2)^{-1}$.

Comment: :thanks, now I got the logic!!